# how do functions read pointers?

Tags: c++, class, oop, object, pointers

im new to c++. I made this simple program using classes  which does simple stuff like change instances of objects and copying objects.

But I'm confused how functions like `std::strlen()` read pointers.As far as i know pointer is just an address to another variable.If i pass in derefrenced pointer in `std::strlen(*c)` i get some error saying compiler cannot convert pointer to char, but if i pass in raw pointer like `std::strlen(c)`
the code compiles fine and gives the desired output.Why is that?`std::strlen()` should know the exact string to calculate length right?how does passing pointer help?

Same goes with `strcpy_s()` if i pass in derefrenced pointers like this `strcpy_s(*str,strlen(str)+1,*c)` it wont work but if i pass in pointers like `strcpy_s(str,strlen(str) + 1, c)`, it works perfectly.

Please help me out as I'm really confused.Thanks

here is the code-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>

class mystring
{
    char* str;

public:
    //constructors

    mystring();
    mystring(const char* c);
    mystring(const mystring& original);
    ~mystring();

    //methods

    void display() const;
    void length() const;
    void display_vector(const std::vector <mystring>& thing) const;

    //operator overloading
    mystring& operator= (const mystring& source);
};

mystring::mystring()                                                                    //default constructor
    :str(nullptr)
{
    str = new char[1];
    *str = '\0';
}

mystring::mystring(const char* c)                                                       //overloded constructor (char *c)
{
    str = new char[std::strlen(c) + 1];
    strcpy_s(str, std::strlen(c) + 1, c);
}

mystring::mystring(const mystring& original)                                            // copy constructor
{
    str = new char[strlen(original.str) + 1];
    strcpy_s(str, strlen(original.str) + 1, original.str);
}

mystring::~mystring()                                                                   //destructor
{
    delete[] str;
}

void mystring::display() const                                                          // display method for mystring
{
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
}

void mystring::length() const                                                           // length fuc
{
    std::cout << strlen(str) << std::endl;
}


mystring& mystring::operator= (const mystring& source)                                  //= operator overload       
{
    delete[] this->str;
    this->str = new char[std::strlen(source.str) + 1];
    strcpy_s(this->str, std::strlen(source.str) + 1, source.str);
    return *this;   
}


int main()
{
    mystring v{ "v_and_jackie" };
    v.display();
    mystring jackie;

    jackie = v;
    jackie.display();
    std::vector <mystring> thing;
    thing.push_back("wake up");
    thing.push_back("samurai");
    for (const auto i : thing)
        i.display();
}
```

Thanks again.

Comment: `pointer is just an address to another variable.` That's not true. A pointer is an address of some object or array, but that doesn't have to be another variable, it can be *dynamically allocated* (and in practise usually is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::strlen` receives as an argument a pointer to the beginning of the string:

> ```
> std::size_t strlen( const char* str );
> ```
>
> Returns the length of the given byte string, that is, **the number of characters in a character array whose first element is pointed to by `str` up to and not including the first null character**. The behavior is undefined if there is no null character in the character array pointed to by `str`.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen

Comment: @default-303 `mystring::display()` returns nothing (`void`).

Comment: sry my bad.i wrote something else.Here is what i wanted to say -can you also please explain how the display() works? `std::cout << str` should print out a pointer but it prints whatever string its pointing to. If i write `std::cout << *str; `it just prints out the first char of the string`str`, if i want the whole string i need to use for loop.So just writing `std::cout << str` looks more simple.Can you explain how this works as well??

Comment: @default-303, dereferencing `str` prints the first character of the string, it's as if you had `str[0]`.

Comment: yes i know that but why `std::cout << str` prints the string while `std::cout << *str' does not?

Comment: @default-303 `<< operator` has overloads to print a single character or an array of characters, if you pass it `*str` it will choose the overload to print a single `char`, if you pass it `str` it will choose the overload to print `const char*`, the compiler chooses the more appropriate overload.

Comment: @default-303, that's what we're here for :) if you have any more doubts don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: @default-303 [operator<<(std::basic_ostream)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2)

Answer (score 1):

> As far as i know pointer is just an address to another variable

Correct.

> If i pass in derefrenced pointer in std::strlen(*c) i get some error saying compiler cannot convert pointer to char

Read the message again. It should say that it cannot convert a char to a pointer-to-char.

> but if i pass in raw pointer like std::strlen(c) the code compiles fine and gives the desired output.Why is that?

This is because of type safety that C++ language has. `std::strlen` accepts an argument that is a pointer to char. If you pass the function something that isn't a pointer to char nor convertible to such pointer, like a char object for example, then the program is ill-formed, and you'll get an informative message pointing out your mistake.

When you indirect through a pointer, what you get back is not a pointer of same type. Instead, the value that you get back is the pointed object, which always has a different type. In case of pointer to char, the pointed object is a char.

> how does passing pointer help?

Passing an argument of correct type into a function call helps.

Comment: thanks a lot.can you also please explain how the `display()` works? `std::cout << str` should print out a pointer but it prints whatever string its pointing to. If i write `std::cout << *str;` it just prints out the first char of the string `str`, if i want the whole string i need to use for loop.So just writing `std::cout << str` looks more simple.Can you explain how this works as well??

Comment: @default-303 There is a loop inside the function that overloads `std::cout.operator<<(char*)`.

Comment: ooh thanks a lot for your help and patience, finally got it

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna try and explain the reasoning behind why you have to pass a char:

Back in the days memory was very valuable. And instead of using memory for an Integer to keep track of the string length a convention was used: End the string with a **null-byte** (zero).

Every character is saved in the ASCII format (lookup ASCII table).
Because every string is null-terminated `"Hello"` would look like `{72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 0}` in memory.

So to get the length of the string you need a pointer to the first character, then advance forwards until you get to the null-byte. By counting how many bytes you advanced in memory you know the amount of characters contained in the string.

This is exactly what `strlen` does.

By dereferencing the pointer to the first character you get the first character.
This way `strlen` would not know where the first character came from in memory and cannot read the next character.
So you can think of dereferencing the pointer to a string (the first char) as loosing all information about that string except what the first character is.

Hopefully this was understandable.